# Does there something called a-come exist in English?

Tags: lyrics

[Source](http://www.daizex.com/multimedia/lyrics/eng-rock_the_dragon.html)

> Dragon! Dragon! Rock the Dragon!
>    Come, **a-come** get me!

Also while listening to the song, I did not feel like they say Come, **a-come** get me!

Is there any meaning existing or is it just for sound effects?

Listen to the song at 0:42 at [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dP75aZvWVdw).

Comment: No meaning, it's just an effect to maintain rhythm.

Comment: Do you have a link to the song or video so we can listen to it?

Comment: It has the look of the sort of fossilized expressions we find in children's games that are many hundreds of years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I heard *a come* at 0:42.  It's just a rhythmic filler sound. When you listen to sung language, you're gonna hear a lot of "extra syllables" thrown in because the artist is singing music, not prose. But sometimes it'll be due to dialect: See ['in-a my heart' correct, or only 'in my heart'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72749/in-a-my-heart-correct-or-only-in-my-heart).

In contexts other than the one you ask about, *a come* could be part of a dialect other than standard English. That is what appears to be happening in the publication called

> Dem a come

([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=ceRzAAAAIAAJ&q="a-come"&dq="a-come"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGw4DPmYfOAhUHySYKHUj3C-YQ6AEIMTAE))

where *dem* is most likely a representation of the pronoun *them* (in subject position, where standard English would use *they*) and *a* could be a shortening of *of* or *have*, as it is in *I'd a come*. See [If Ida Been Here, Ida Been There](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96726/if-ida-been-here-ida-been-there).

English does has the gerund form *a-coming*, whose usage can be traced to Old English. See [a fighting for the glory - how do you understand this type of grammar?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49923/a-fighting-for-the-glory-how-do-you-understand-this-type-of-grammar)  and the ELU links from that question.

It is possible that speakers  who nowadays say *I'm a-coming* could say *a-come and get me*. That is not  what is happening in the music  you cite.

Comment: Song added there

Comment: Thank you, because it is always best to listen to how written lyrics are actually sung,  in order to  attempt to form an interpretation.